# I need to delete new line characters in a .CSV file that has more than 50,000 rows. Need linux command.

Tags: unix

I have a .CSV file with 52,000 rows. Each row has 13 columns separated by a delimiter '|'. Bad data is being inserted in 11th row and due to which new line characters are being incuded in the file. I'm supposed to delete them.

Comment: Hello Kiran, welcome to Stackoverflow! Please give us more information - what have you tried so far (code)? This is a good source to how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: On Linux, every line of a file has a newline character at the end. Can you be more specific about which newlines you want to delete?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this;

```
awk -F '|' -v fields=13 '{c+=NF; s=(s?s OFS:"") $0} c>=fields{print s; s=""; c=0}' yourfile.csv


user@host:/tmp$cat test
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11
|12|13
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|
11|12|13


user@host:/tmp$ awk -F"|" -v fields=13 '{f+=NF; str=(str?str OFS:"") $0} f>=fields{print str; str=""; f=0}' test
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11 |12|13
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10| 11|12|13
```

Comment: There is no newline character in that string. Try it with `echo -e`.